# Dockerfile with copy command and relative path

Tags: unit-testing, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

Have some way to use copy command with the relative path in dockerfile? I'm trying to use:

```
COPY ./../folder/*.csproj ./
```

OBS.: My struct folder (I'm running the dockerfile on project-test and other files are in the project-console folder) is:

```
|- project-console
|- project-test
```

And I receive the following error:

ERROR: service 'app' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified.

***My purpose is*** have two projects in the same docker. I have a dotnet core console and another with a unity test (NUnity), I'm trying to run the unity test in docker.

***UPDATE***

Is possible to use Multi-stage: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Or using docker-compose with build: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Like:

```
services: 

worker:
    build:
      context: ./workers
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reference: [Allow Dockerfile from outside build-context](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/886)

You can try this way

```sh
$ cd project-console
$ docker build -f ../project-test/Dockerfile .
```

**Update**:

By using docker-compose

```
build:
  context: ../
  dockerfile: project-test/Dockerfile
```

`../` will be set as the context, it should include project-console and project-test in your case. So that you can `COPY` project-console/*.csproj in Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @Kuanlin Chen, Im using docker-compose and I need to do this inside the Dockerfile. Do you know another way to do that?

Comment: Hi @TitaoYamamoto I have updated my answer, please have a try.